# How pass only some string values from one string list to enother

Tags: c#, list

I have array string list that is actually a csv file that every filed of this list is a file row .
In this csv file (List) i have more then 20 columns and i need to create a new list that will contain only specific columns from the original list .
how can i do that ? 
this is the list:

```
List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();
        parsedData = ParseResultCSV();
```

Comment: This question is overly broad and looks like a request for code-writing service. I would suggest to close it. Thanks for the understanding. Best regards,

Comment: `var newList = oldList.Where(x => x.Contains("stackoverflow")).ToList();` is an answer to titular question. But parsing CSV is quite different problem, you should rephrase it as 2 different questions as you ask 2 different things.

Answer (score 0):

Every cell in a CSV file is separated with a ';'.
So something like this:

```
var listOfParsedValues = new List<List<string>>();
foreach(var row in parsedData){
   var cells = row.Split(';');
   // if you for example want to save values at cell 4 and 7:
   var valuesOfThisRow;
   valuesOfThisRow.Add(cells[4]);
   valuesOfThisRow.Add(cells[7]);
   listOfParsedValues.Add(valuesOfThisRow);
}
```

Not optimal, but it works :)